# Configure is missing while setting up the tool chain

Tags: riscv

I am trying to setup the RISC-V tool chain. I am following the instructions which is specified in the RISC V website. the steps are

step 1 : git submodule update --init --recursive
step 2 : export RISCV=/path/to/install/riscv/toolchain
step 3 : ./build.sh

while running the script an error is encountered with build.common
The error is 
**"build.common: line 30: ../configure: No such file or directory"**

could some one try to resolve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the configure file is missing, then it seems like perhaps your submodules did not update correctly.  Did you run the first step without errors?

If you look in each sub-directory, you should see a file named `configure`.  If not, make sure to run:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```